# Is there any open hardware microcontroller?

Tags: embedded, hardware, microcontroller

Is there any open hardware microcontroller?. I can't find something about this.

I mean microcontroller which i can buy from vendors or somewhere and i can download and see full scheme of it. And this information enough to emulate it. something like it.

Comment: The closet you will get probably is one implemented in an FPGA. Not sure many OSS devs have access to a custom chip fab.

Comment: What do you mean with open hardware?

Comment: Not sure of the meaning either, and besides what would you do if there was an "open" hardware? Hand bond the MCU? Build a silicon fab in your garage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they opened up the code for the propeller yes?  and you can get an msp430 clone on opecores or an arm2 on opencores as well as the or1k and 2k, plus a myriad of other open source cores there and elsewhere (just google it).   The lm32 is open, and the mico8 is maybe, certainly can be used on a lattice part.  But you can certainly find cores like that from each of the fpga/cpld vendors, tuned for and likely free on their platforms.   Plus what is it the 68hc11 there are free and or for purchase cores, probably 8051s, etc.  And of course there is the cortex-m1, not open but if you wanted a microcontroller in source form to implement on your platform.

The propeller is probably the closest to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean with "open hardware microcontroller". For professionals it's much better to buy a microcontroller or a microcontroller design (ARM for example). Hobbyists usually don't have access to a fab and the required tooling to create their own ASIC.

If you're interested in implementations for FPGAs on the other hand, you should check out the site http://opencores.org/projects where you can find (among other things) different open-source processors.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, SPARC is fully "open", both in it's early conception, and then again later in life by Sun.  I think short of some big-iron stuff (that's gradually been taken over by x86), it's basically dead.  Maybe you could revive it?